# Ansible - how to compare two dictionaries with same keys

Tags: dictionary, ansible, compare

I have two dictionaries:

```
source_list:
  myFlag1: true
  MyFlag2: false
```

And second dict:

```
target_list:
  MyFlag1: false
  MyFlag2: false
```

Keys are identical always, but the order is not strict yet.
How can i highlight the difference between them?
I can use dict2items to convert lists to

```
source_list:
  - key: MyFlag1
    value: true
  - key: MyFlag2
    value: false
```

But again i'm confused, how can i compare them... Of course, i can loop ov er two dicts and compare it one by one, but it doesn't look really effective.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q: ***"How to compare two dictionaries with the same keys?"***

A: Given the simplified data for testing

```yaml
    s:
      flag1: true
      Flag3: true
      flag2: false
    t:
      flag3: true
      flag1: false
      flag2: false
```

- Compare the variables to briefly find out whether there are any differences or not, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: The dictionaries are identical
      when: s == t
    - debug:
        msg: The dictionaries are different
      when: s != t
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: The dictionaries are different
```

- Next, compare the keys, e.g. declare the variables

```yaml
    s_keys: "{{ s.keys()|list }}"
    t_keys: "{{ t.keys()|list }}"
    diff_keys: "{{ s_keys|symmetric_difference(t_keys) }}"
```

and test the length of the *symmetric_difference*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "The difference in the keys: {{ diff_keys }}"
      when:  diff_keys|length != 0
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'The difference in the keys: [''Flag3'', ''flag3'']'
```

- Let's assume dictionaries with identical keys to finding different values, e.g.

```yaml
    s:
      flag1: true
      flag3: true
      flag2: false
    t:
      flag3: true
      flag1: false
      flag2: false
```

- Iterate the list of keys and compare the dictionaries item by item, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is {{ (s[item] == t[item])|ternary('OK', 'KO') }}"
      loop: "{{ s.keys()|sort }}"
      when:  diff_keys|length == 0
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: flag1 is KO
  msg: flag2 is OK
  msg: flag3 is OK
```

---

Q: ***"How can I highlight the difference between them?"***

A: Create a dictionary with the different values only, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        diff_vals: "{{ diff_vals|d({})|combine({item: s[item]}) }}"
      loop: "{{ s.keys()|sort }}"
      when:
        - diff_keys|length == 0
        - s[item] != t[item]
    - debug:
        var: diff_vals
```

gives

```yaml
  diff_vals:
    flag1: true
```

---

**Example of a complete playbook**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    s:
      flag1: true
      flag3: true
      flag2: false
    t:
      flag3: true
      flag1: false
      flag2: false
    
    s_keys: "{{ s.keys()|list }}"
    t_keys: "{{ t.keys()|list }}"
    diff_keys: "{{ s_keys|symmetric_difference(t_keys) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: The dictionaries are identical
      when: s == t
    - debug:
        msg: The dictionaries are different
      when: s != t

    - debug:
        msg: "The difference in the keys: {{ diff_keys }}"
      when:  diff_keys|length != 0

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is {{ (s[item] == t[item])|ternary('OK', 'KO') }}"
      loop: "{{ s.keys()|sort }}"
      when:  diff_keys|length == 0

    - set_fact:
        diff_vals: "{{ diff_vals|d({})|combine({item: s[item]}) }}"
      loop: "{{ s.keys()|sort }}"
      when:
        - diff_keys|length == 0
        - s[item] != t[item]
    - debug:
        var: diff_vals
```

Comment: Vladimir, your code shows the error for me.
`The conditional check 'source_list.keys()|symmetric_difference(target_list.keys())|length == 0' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if source_list.keys()|symmetric_difference(target_list.keys())|length == 0 %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_keys' and 'dict_keys'`

Comment: Well, i use Python3. The solution is to use the |list filter to transform the dict_keys object returns by the .keys() method into a simple list.

Comment: Thank you very much Vladimir!