# Create two lists and compare them

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to make two lists and compare them, but there's one thing. The lists have different places of double quotes.

Yaml with tasks:

```yaml
---
- name: Get default role counts
  set_fact:
    roles_info: "{{ lookup('roles_info', wantlist=True) }}"

- name: Get role counts from file
  set_fact:
    roles_info_from_yaml: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/stack/templates/general/node-info.yaml').splitlines() }}"

- name: Remove whitespace
  set_fact:
    rm_spaces: "{{ item | trim }}"
  loop: "{{ roles_info_from_yaml[1:] }}"
  register: roles_excl_spaces

- name: Remove Count from roles
  set_fact:
    roles: "{{ roles_excl_spaces.results | regex_replace('Count') }}"

- name: Make a list from yaml
  set_fact:
    roles_list_from_yaml: "{{ roles | map(attribute='ansible_facts.rm_spaces') | reverse | list }}"

- name: Make a list from Heat and Swift
  set_fact:
    roles_list_from_db: "{{ roles_list_from_db | default([]) | combine({item[0]: item[1]}) }}"
  loop: "{{ (roles_info | map(attribute='name') | zip(roles_info | map(attribute='count'))) | list }}"

- debug: var=roles_list_from_yaml
- debug: var=roles_list_from_db

- name: Fail when the quantitative value in the database and yaml-file do not match
  fail:
    msg: Different quantitative values
  failed_when: lists_checking | length > 0
  vars:
    lists_checking: "{{ roles_list_from_db | difference(roles_list_from_yaml) }}"
```

Output:

```bash
TASK [node_info_count : Get default role counts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:2
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_info": [
            {
                "count": 3,
                "flavor": "baremetal",
                "name": "ControllerNoCeph"
            },
            {
                "count": 2,
                "flavor": "baremetal",
                "name": "Compute4pOvPa1g"
            },
            {
                "count": 0,
                "flavor": "baremetal",
                "name": "Compute4pOvPa"
            },
            {
                "count": 2,
                "flavor": "baremetal",
                "name": "Compute6pSrPa1g"
            },
            {
                "count": 2,
                "flavor": "baremetal",
                "name": "Compute6pDpPa1g"
            }
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [node_info_count : Get role counts from file] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:6
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_info_from_yaml": [
            "parameter_defaults:",
            "  ControllerNoCephCount: 3",
            "  Compute6pSrPa1gCount: 2",
            "  Compute6pDpPa1gCount: 2",
            "  Compute4pOvPa1gCount: 2",
            "  Compute4pOvPaCount: 0"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [node_info_count : Remove whitespace] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:10
ok: [undercloud] => (item=  ControllerNoCephCount: 3) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "rm_spaces": "ControllerNoCephCount: 3"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "  ControllerNoCephCount: 3"
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=  Compute6pSrPa1gCount: 2) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "rm_spaces": "Compute6pSrPa1gCount: 2"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "  Compute6pSrPa1gCount: 2"
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=  Compute6pDpPa1gCount: 2) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "rm_spaces": "Compute6pDpPa1gCount: 2"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "  Compute6pDpPa1gCount: 2"
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=  Compute4pOvPa1gCount: 2) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "rm_spaces": "Compute4pOvPa1gCount: 2"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "  Compute4pOvPa1gCount: 2"
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=  Compute4pOvPaCount: 0) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "rm_spaces": "Compute4pOvPaCount: 0"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "  Compute4pOvPaCount: 0"
}

TASK [node_info_count : Remove Count from roles] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:16
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles": [
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "rm_spaces": "ControllerNoCeph: 3"
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "  ControllerNoCeph: 3"
            },
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "rm_spaces": "Compute6pSrPa1g: 2"
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "  Compute6pSrPa1g: 2"
            },
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "rm_spaces": "Compute6pDpPa1g: 2"
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "  Compute6pDpPa1g: 2"
            },
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "rm_spaces": "Compute4pOvPa1g: 2"
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "  Compute4pOvPa1g: 2"
            },
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "rm_spaces": "Compute4pOvPa: 0"
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "  Compute4pOvPa: 0"
            }
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [node_info_count : Make a list from yaml] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:20
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_list_from_yaml": [
            "Compute4pOvPa: 0",
            "Compute4pOvPa1g: 2",
            "Compute6pDpPa1g: 2",
            "Compute6pSrPa1g: 2",
            "ControllerNoCeph: 3"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [node_info_count : Make a list from Heat and Swift] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:24
ok: [undercloud] => (item=['ControllerNoCeph', 3]) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_list_from_db": {
            "ControllerNoCeph": 3
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": [
        "ControllerNoCeph",
        3
    ]
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=['Compute4pOvPa1g', 2]) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_list_from_db": {
            "Compute4pOvPa1g": 2,
            "ControllerNoCeph": 3
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": [
        "Compute4pOvPa1g",
        2
    ]
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=['Compute4pOvPa', 0]) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_list_from_db": {
            "Compute4pOvPa": 0,
            "Compute4pOvPa1g": 2,
            "ControllerNoCeph": 3
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": [
        "Compute4pOvPa",
        0
    ]
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=['Compute6pSrPa1g', 2]) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_list_from_db": {
            "Compute4pOvPa": 0,
            "Compute4pOvPa1g": 2,
            "Compute6pSrPa1g": 2,
            "ControllerNoCeph": 3
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": [
        "Compute6pSrPa1g",
        2
    ]
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=['Compute6pDpPa1g', 2]) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_list_from_db": {
            "Compute4pOvPa": 0,
            "Compute4pOvPa1g": 2,
            "Compute6pDpPa1g": 2,
            "Compute6pSrPa1g": 2,
            "ControllerNoCeph": 3
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": [
        "Compute6pDpPa1g",
        2
    ]
}

TASK [node_info_count : debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:29
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "roles_list_from_yaml": [
        "Compute4pOvPa: 0",
        "Compute4pOvPa1g: 2",
        "Compute6pDpPa1g: 2",
        "Compute6pSrPa1g: 2",
        "ControllerNoCeph: 3"
    ]
}

TASK [node_info_count : debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:30
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "roles_list_from_db": {
        "Compute4pOvPa": 0,
        "Compute4pOvPa1g": 2,
        "Compute6pDpPa1g": 2,
        "Compute6pSrPa1g": 2,
        "ControllerNoCeph": 3
    }
}

TASK [node_info_count : Fail when the quantitative value in the database and yaml-file do not match] *****************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:32
fatal: [undercloud]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed_when_result": true,
    "msg": "Different quantitative values"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
undercloud                 : ok=8    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I got two different lists, but they should be the same.

```bash
TASK [node_info_count : debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:29
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "roles_list_from_yaml": [
        "Compute4pOvPa: 0",
        "Compute4pOvPa1g: 2",
        "Compute6pDpPa1g: 2",
        "Compute6pSrPa1g: 2",
        "ControllerNoCeph: 3"
    ]
}

TASK [node_info_count : debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:30
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "roles_list_from_db": {
        "Compute4pOvPa": 0,
        "Compute4pOvPa1g": 2,
        "Compute6pDpPa1g": 2,
        "Compute6pSrPa1g": 2,
        "ControllerNoCeph": 3
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what I need to redo in the tasks above to make the double quotes the same for these two lists, so that the last task doesn't fail?

Comment: Look into validation of the : pipe character.

Comment: Is there any reason why reading the variables out of the file in such a complicated and clumsy way with `set_fact:
    roles_info_from_yaml: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/stack/templates/general/node-info.yaml').splitlines() }}"` and further instead of just using [`include_vars` module – Load variables from files, dynamically within a task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html)?

Comment: As it looks currently like [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me, if providing the content of `/home/stack/templates/general/node-info.yaml` or better a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) one probably could come up with a simple answer here.

Comment: @U880D The contents of the `/home/stack/templates/general/node-info.yaml` file can be found at https://pastebin.com/DT0eCy8g. I also tried to use [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html), it's actually more useful, but the node-info.yaml file has parameter_defaults, which prevents me from doing the comparison and I don't know how to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a var file `node-info.yml`

```yaml
parameter_defaults:
  ControllerNoCephCount: 3
  Compute6pSrPa1gCount: 2
  Compute6pDpPa1gCount: 2
  Compute4pOvPa1gCount: 2
  Compute4pOvPaCount: 0
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

   roles_list_from_db:
     Compute4pOvPa: 0
     Compute4pOvPa1g: 2
     Compute6pDpPa1g: 2
     Compute6pSrPa1g: 2
     ControllerNoCeph: 3

  tasks:

  - name: Get role counts from file
    include_vars:
      file: node-info.yml
      name: roles_list_from_yaml

  - debug:
      var: roles_list_from_db

  - debug:
      var: roles_list_from_yaml
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***********
ok: [localhost] =>
  roles_list_from_db:
    Compute4pOvPa: 0
    Compute4pOvPa1g: 2
    Compute6pDpPa1g: 2
    Compute6pSrPa1g: 2
    ControllerNoCeph: 3

TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] =>
  roles_list_from_yaml:
    parameter_defaults:
      Compute4pOvPa1gCount: 2
      Compute4pOvPaCount: 0
      Compute6pDpPa1gCount: 2
      Compute6pSrPa1gCount: 2
      ControllerNoCephCount: 3
```

It is noticed that the data structures and key names differ and need to be adjusted.

---

Since it is not possible in Ansible to modify variables in place, it will be  necessary to [`update_fact` – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html) or [`set_fact` – Set host variable(s) and fact(s)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html) new instead. And especially because key names will change.

In order to do so a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

   roles_list_from_db:
     Compute4pOvPa: 0
     Compute4pOvPa1g: 2
     Compute6pDpPa1g: 2
     Compute6pSrPa1g: 2
     ControllerNoCeph: 3

  tasks:

  - name: Get role counts from file
    include_vars:
      file: node-info.yml
      name: roles_list_from_yaml

  - name: Adjust data structure
    set_fact:
      roles_list_from_yaml_renamed: "{{ roles_list_from_yaml_renamed | default({})|
                                        combine({ translation[item.key] |
                                        default(item.key): item.value}) }}"
    loop: "{{ roles_list_from_yaml.parameter_defaults | dict2items }}"
    vars:
      translation:
        Compute4pOvPaCount: Compute4pOvPa
        Compute4pOvPa1gCount: Compute4pOvPa1g
        Compute6pDpPa1gCount: Compute6pDpPa1g
        Compute6pSrPa1gCount: Compute6pSrPa1g
        ControllerNoCephCount: ControllerNoCeph

  - debug:
      var: roles_list_from_db

  - debug:
      var: roles_list_from_yaml_renamed
```

shows this with `set_fact`, resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************
ok: [localhost] =>
  roles_list_from_db:
    Compute4pOvPa: 0
    Compute4pOvPa1g: 2
    Compute6pDpPa1g: 2
    Compute6pSrPa1g: 2
    ControllerNoCeph: 3

TASK [debug] ******************
ok: [localhost] =>
  roles_list_from_yaml_renamed:
    Compute4pOvPa: 0
    Compute4pOvPa1g: 2
    Compute6pDpPa1g: 2
    Compute6pSrPa1g: 2
    ControllerNoCeph: 3
```

During this the nested key `roles_list_from_yaml.parameter_defaults` was easy to drop.

**Credits To**

- [How to change dictionary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60778966/6771046)

---

It is also noticed that **the data structures are in fact dicts!** Therefore it is recommended to change the variable names from `roles_list_from_db|yaml` to `roles_from_db|yaml`. Since the variable names choosed are misleading, the `_list` should be removed. This will avoid confusion and wrong assumptions. See [`type_debug` filter – show input data type](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/type_debug_filter.html).

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  roles_from_db | type_debug: dict

TASK [debug] *******************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  roles_from_yaml_renamed | type_debug: dict
```

A comparison becomes trivial now

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: The dictionaries are identical
    when: roles_from_db == roles_from_yaml_renamed

  - debug:
      msg: The dictionaries are different
    when: roles_from_db != roles_from_yaml_renamed
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: The dictionaries are identical
```

**Credits To**

- [How to compare two dictionaries with the same keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58487241/6771046)

---

Further readings and documentation which might help in this case

- [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- [How to work with lists and dictionaries in Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-lists-dictionaries-yaml)
- [Using variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html)
- [Manipulating data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html)

Answer (score 0):

After researching the Ansible documentation and searching Google for solutions to similar issues, I did the following set of tasks:

```yaml
---
- name: Get current roles info from Heat and Swift
  set_fact:
    roles_db: "{{ lookup('roles_info', wantlist=True) }}"

- name: Get roles info from yaml file
  include_vars:
    file: /home/stack/templates/general/node-info.yaml
    name: roles_yaml

- name: Generate dict from Heat and Swift
  set_fact:
    roles_info_from_db: "{{ roles_info_from_db | default([]) | combine({item[0]: item[1]}) }}"
  loop: "{{ (roles_db | map(attribute='name') | zip(roles_db | map(attribute='count'))) | list }}"

- name: Remove 'Count' suffix from roles
  set_fact:
    roles_info_from_yaml: "{{ roles_yaml | regex_replace('Count') }}"

- name: Make dict from previous task as itemized list
  set_fact:
    node_info_db: "{{ roles_info_from_db | dict2items }}"

- name: Exclude 'parameter_defaults' from dict created from yaml
  set_fact:
    node_info: "{{ roles_info_from_yaml | json_query('parameter_defaults') | dict2items }}"

- name: Fail when the quantitative value in Heat-Swift and yaml-file do not match
  fail:
    msg: "Different quantitative values: {{ diff_keys }}"
  failed_when: diff_keys|length > 0
  vars:
    diff_keys: "{{ node_info | difference(node_info_db) }}"
```

It works as I wanted.

Output:

```bash
TASK [node_info_count : Get current roles info from Heat and Swift] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:2
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_db": [
            {
                "count": 3,
                "flavor": "baremetal",
                "name": "ControllerNoCeph"
            },
            {
                "count": 2,
                "flavor": "baremetal",
                "name": "Compute4pOvPa1g"
            },
            {
                "count": 0,
                "flavor": "baremetal",
                "name": "Compute4pOvPa"
            },
            {
                "count": 2,
                "flavor": "baremetal",
                "name": "Compute6pSrPa1g"
            },
            {
                "count": 2,
                "flavor": "baremetal",
                "name": "Compute6pDpPa1g"
            }
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [node_info_count : Get roles info from yaml file] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:6
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_yaml": {
            "parameter_defaults": {
                "Compute4pOvPa1gCount": 2,
                "Compute4pOvPaCount": 1,
                "Compute6pDpPa1gCount": 2,
                "Compute6pSrPa1gCount": 2,
                "ControllerNoCephCount": 3
            }
        }
    },
    "ansible_included_var_files": [
        "/home/stack/templates/general/node-info.yaml"
    ],
    "changed": false
}

TASK [node_info_count : Generate dict from Heat and Swift] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:11
ok: [undercloud] => (item=['ControllerNoCeph', 3]) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_info_from_db": {
            "ControllerNoCeph": 3
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": [
        "ControllerNoCeph",
        3
    ]
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=['Compute4pOvPa1g', 2]) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_info_from_db": {
            "Compute4pOvPa1g": 2,
            "ControllerNoCeph": 3
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": [
        "Compute4pOvPa1g",
        2
    ]
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=['Compute4pOvPa', 0]) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_info_from_db": {
            "Compute4pOvPa": 0,
            "Compute4pOvPa1g": 2,
            "ControllerNoCeph": 3
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": [
        "Compute4pOvPa",
        0
    ]
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=['Compute6pSrPa1g', 2]) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_info_from_db": {
            "Compute4pOvPa": 0,
            "Compute4pOvPa1g": 2,
            "Compute6pSrPa1g": 2,
            "ControllerNoCeph": 3
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": [
        "Compute6pSrPa1g",
        2
    ]
}
ok: [undercloud] => (item=['Compute6pDpPa1g', 2]) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_info_from_db": {
            "Compute4pOvPa": 0,
            "Compute4pOvPa1g": 2,
            "Compute6pDpPa1g": 2,
            "Compute6pSrPa1g": 2,
            "ControllerNoCeph": 3
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": [
        "Compute6pDpPa1g",
        2
    ]
}

TASK [node_info_count : Remove 'Count' suffix from roles] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:16
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "roles_info_from_yaml": {
            "parameter_defaults": {
                "Compute4pOvPa": 1,
                "Compute4pOvPa1g": 2,
                "Compute6pDpPa1g": 2,
                "Compute6pSrPa1g": 2,
                "ControllerNoCeph": 3
            }
        }
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [node_info_count : Make dict from previous task as itemized list] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:20
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "node_info_db": [
            {
                "key": "ControllerNoCeph",
                "value": 3
            },
            {
                "key": "Compute4pOvPa1g",
                "value": 2
            },
            {
                "key": "Compute4pOvPa",
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "key": "Compute6pSrPa1g",
                "value": 2
            },
            {
                "key": "Compute6pDpPa1g",
                "value": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [node_info_count : Exclude 'parameter_defaults' from dict created from yaml] ************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:24
ok: [undercloud] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "node_info": [
            {
                "key": "ControllerNoCeph",
                "value": 3
            },
            {
                "key": "Compute4pOvPa1g",
                "value": 2
            },
            {
                "key": "Compute6pSrPa1g",
                "value": 2
            },
            {
                "key": "Compute6pDpPa1g",
                "value": 2
            },
            {
                "key": "Compute4pOvPa",
                "value": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [node_info_count : Fail when the quantitative value in Heat-Swift and yaml-file do not match] *******************************************************************************************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible/roles/node_info_count/tasks/main.yml:28
fatal: [undercloud]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed_when_result": true,
    "msg": "Different quantitative values: [{'key': 'Compute4pOvPa', 'value': 1}]"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
undercloud                 : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Thanks for the tip about [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html) to user U880D